# posts disappearing from feed when like button is pressed

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, state

I am using the following function to update posts in my feed:

```
func fetchPosts() {
    let query = COLLECTION_POSTS
        .order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)

    query.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, _ in
        guard let changes = snapshot?.documentChanges.filter({$0.type == .added}) else {return}

        self.posts = changes.compactMap {
            do {
                return try $0.document.data(as: Post.self)
            } catch {
                print("Error converting Firestore document to Post object: \(error)")
                return nil
            }
        }
        self.fetchUserPosts()
    }
}
```

When I like a post and update the like count the posts disappear from the feed, then I get a debug message via the self.fetchuserposts() function that there are no posts on the database. However, despite this, the likes still increase on the server side.

The following is the code that updates the like field when a user presses it:

```
func likePost(post: Post) {
    guard let uid  = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    guard let postId = post.id else { return }
    let userLikesRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).collection("user-likes")
        
    Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").document(postId)
        .updateData(["likes" : post.likes + 1]) { _ in
            userLikesRef.document(postId).setData([:]) { _ in
                self.isLiked = true
            }
        }
}
```

I have tried many different methods of updating the like field but I cannot seem to figure it out. I expect that there is maybe an issue where the model is not being updated but that does not make sense to me given that the snapshot listener is listening for changes.

Answer (score 0):

I (jankily) fixed this issue using the folllowing code. However, all posts in the feed reload when pressing the like button, not ideal, I would still appreciate help if anyone has a better solution!

```
func fetchPosts() {

    let query = COLLECTION_POSTS
        .order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)

    query.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, _ in
        guard let changes = snapshot?.documentChanges else {return}

        for change in changes {
            
            if change.type == .added {
                do {
                    let post = try change.document.data(as: Post.self)
                    self.postsArray.append(post)
                } catch {
                    print("Error converting Firestore document to Post object: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        self.posts = self.postsArray
        self.fetchUserPosts()
    }
}
```